All ASP.NET Core applications started throwing ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error
I encountered an incomprehensible problem.
All existing ASP.NET Core Web API applications started to throw an error "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" when debugging in Visual Studio 2022.
SSL support for applications was initially enabled, the code did not change. No proxy.
At the same time, older applications on .NET framework continue to launch normally.
Tried:

Delete localhost certificates from the Personal and Trusted Root Certification Authorities folders.
Didn't help, the certificate for IISExpress was automatically added again after launching applications on .NET Core.


How about you directly using the HTTP and comment the app.UseHttpsRedirection();?

No effect for app.UseHttpsRedirection() :(

How about directly running the application using the dot net run? Besides, you couldn't run this application in http environment ?
